# Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm doing a discord alt generator.
the basic idea is, I type !generate and the bot dm's me with an account.
my problem is that my bot can't send any messages to the author of the message.
I'm getting "Cannot send messages to this user".

Lil code

```
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
 .addField("alt", `account: \n${random}`)
 .setColor("#fffff");
message.author.send(embed);
```

random function picks random alt ( test:test for example from a txt file ).

any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The user you are sending the RichEmbed to likely has DM's from server members disabled.**

Make sure that `message.author` does not have DM's from server members disabled in their privacy settings.