# discord.js dm a user in the "guildBanAdd" event

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a ban appeal system for my discord server, where when an account is banned, whether its by a command or manually by a mod, it will DM the user (if it can) to let them know they can appeal the ban. This will then be reviewed by myself, and myself only and then I will unban if I feel like I should do so. (I know everyone with ban perms can unban, but I should be able to trust them not to as I've selected them to be my mods).

Using the documentation here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildBan to see what the `GuildBan` type has that I can use, I look at the `.user` property specifically as I can use the `.send` property of the user to send a message to that user.

However, upon implementing this code, I recieve the error:

```
(node:435) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

Im confused, naturally, because I'm getting the user directly from the `GuildBan` type which I should be able to use the `.send` method to send the message.

I experimented to see why this would be the case, and it seems the parameter `ban` in my code only returns the guild property and nothing else.

Finally here is my code for the event:

````js
client.on("guildBanAdd", async (ban) => {
  console.log(ban);
  console.log(await ban.fetch()); // these both return only guild objects
  ban.user.send("You have been banned from my discord server, you can submit a ban request here using the format provided: \n\n ```BAN APPEAL:\nReason:```");
});
````

In summary, I've used the documentation to write my code, and for some reason the `ban` parameter only contains a guild object, where the docs say it should include the user object as well as some other objects too. This means that I cannot send a DM to the user when they have been banned.

BTW, I'm using discord.js version 12.5.3

What is causing this issue, and could you please show a possible fix?

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` are you using?

Comment: @PerplexingParadox 12.5.3 (double checked as package,json said ^12.5.3, i think its actually 13.0.0)

Comment: You may have to do `await ban.user.fetch()`

Comment: @MrMythical ive just tried this, thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately its still saying user is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your `discord.js` version is 12.5.3, then it says in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.3/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd) that the `guildBanAdd` event emits two parameters: `guild` and `user` (rather than 1 `ban`, for v13). You only assigned `ban` to the `Guild`, hence why you're only getting the `Guild` object. To fix this, you can just put two arguments instead:

```js
client.on("guildBanAdd", async (guild, user) => {
```

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildBanAdd <- this says it takes just the ban parameter but I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Oh, in the top left (assuming you are on a desktop), there's a dropdown where you can change the version of `discord.js` documentation. Your link is currently set to `stable`, which I think is v13 rather than 12.5.3.

Comment: Well, that has definitely sorted it, however now it `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user` My alt does allow messages from the user, however could this be a case of the bot cannot access the user because the user is not in the server?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478389/cannot-send-messages-to-this-user) for more info about that issue.

Comment: As i said, my alt (which is the acc im banning) allows messages from the server already

Comment: That's what you meant by alt. But yes, I do believe that if the bot doesn't share a server at all with your alt account, then you won't be able to send anything, like what this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/b74ebr/can_i_dm_someone_im_not_in_a_server_with_anymore/) states (albeit it's user to user, but close enough).

Comment: i understand why they made it like that though, bc otherwise people will just brute force usernames and spam everyone